# Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] while xpack secrutiy passwords are set

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am setting up a ELK stack on Kubernetes.
Already did it one for pre-prod environment and it is working well. Unfortunately, when trying to duplicate the setup for a prod environment I came across this error :

```
Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]
```

I have xpack security enabled and did setup passwords with `bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords` CLI tool. I then set the generated elastic password in my elastic YAML and restarted my elastic deployment. But I still have this error showing up. I tried resetting the elastic password, same issue. I also have all the needed PVC and Services.

Here is the Kurbenetes YML deployment for my elastic master node if needed :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "4"
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/applied: 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
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/id: 3dc011c2-d20c-465b-a143-2f27f4dc464f
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-06T11:59:47Z"
  generation: 4
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: es01
    objectset.rio.cattle.io/hash: 83a41b68cabf516665877d6d90c837e124ed2029
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kompose.cmd: {}
          f:kompose.version: {}
          f:objectset.rio.cattle.io/applied: {}
          f:objectset.rio.cattle.io/id: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:io.kompose.service: {}
          f:objectset.rio.cattle.io/hash: {}
      f:spec:
        f:progressDeadlineSeconds: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:revisionHistoryLimit: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:strategy:
          f:type: {}
        f:template:
          f:metadata:
            f:annotations:
              .: {}
              f:cattle.io/timestamp: {}
              f:kompose.cmd: {}
              f:kompose.version: {}
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:io.kompose.service: {}
          f:spec:
            f:affinity: {}
            f:containers:
              k:{"name":"es01"}:
                .: {}
                f:env:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"name":"ELASTIC_PASSWORD"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:valueFrom:
                      .: {}
                      f:secretKeyRef:
                        .: {}
                        f:key: {}
                        f:name: {}
                        f:optional: {}
                  k:{"name":"ES_JAVA_OPTS"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"cluster.initial_master_nodes"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"cluster.name"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"discovery.seed_hosts"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"node.name"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.license.self_generated.type"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.enabled"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.http.ssl.key"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.transport.ssl.key"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                  k:{"name":"xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:value: {}
                f:image: {}
                f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:ports:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"containerPort":9200,"protocol":"TCP"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:containerPort: {}
                    f:name: {}
                    f:protocol: {}
                f:resources:
                  .: {}
                  f:limits:
                    .: {}
                    f:memory: {}
                  f:requests:
                    .: {}
                    f:memory: {}
                f:securityContext:
                  .: {}
                  f:allowPrivilegeEscalation: {}
                  f:capabilities: {}
                  f:privileged: {}
                  f:readOnlyRootFilesystem: {}
                  f:runAsUser: {}
                f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                f:volumeMounts:
                  .: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
                  k:{"mountPath":"/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"}:
                    .: {}
                    f:mountPath: {}
                    f:name: {}
            f:dnsPolicy: {}
            f:nodeName: {}
            f:restartPolicy: {}
            f:schedulerName: {}
            f:securityContext:
              .: {}
              f:runAsUser: {}
            f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
            f:volumes:
              .: {}
              k:{"name":"certs"}:
                .: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:persistentVolumeClaim:
                  .: {}
                  f:claimName: {}
              k:{"name":"esdata01"}:
                .: {}
                f:name: {}
                f:persistentVolumeClaim:
                  .: {}
                  f:claimName: {}
    manager: rancher
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-09-06T12:50:29Z"
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: {}
      f:status:
        f:availableReplicas: {}
        f:conditions:
          .: {}
          k:{"type":"Available"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
          k:{"type":"Progressing"}:
            .: {}
            f:lastTransitionTime: {}
            f:lastUpdateTime: {}
            f:message: {}
            f:reason: {}
            f:status: {}
            f:type: {}
        f:observedGeneration: {}
        f:readyReplicas: {}
        f:replicas: {}
        f:updatedReplicas: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-09-06T13:58:46Z"
  name: es01
  namespace: waked-elk-prod
  resourceVersion: "219089408"
  uid: 244c96dc-e6c6-4761-a0db-67bad33b94fa
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: es01
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cattle.io/timestamp: "2022-09-06T12:40:20Z"
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.26.1 (a9d05d509)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: es01
    spec:
      affinity: {}
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: ELASTIC_PASSWORD
              name: elastic-creds-prod
              optional: false
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: es01,es02,es03
        - name: cluster.name
          value: docker-cluster
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: es02,es03
        - name: node.name
          value: es01
        - name: xpack.license.self_generated.type
          value: basic
        - name: xpack.security.enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate
          value: certs/es01/es01.crt
        - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities
          value: certs/ca/ca.crt
        - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.key
          value: certs/es01/es01.key
        - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.verification_mode
          value: certificate
        - name: xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate
          value: certs/es01/es01.crt
        - name: xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities
          value: certs/ca/ca.crt
        - name: xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: xpack.security.transport.ssl.key
          value: certs/es01/es01.key
        - name: xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode
          value: certificate
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms2g -Xmx2g
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: es01
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: 9200tcp
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 10000Mi
          requests:
            memory: 5000Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          capabilities: {}
          privileged: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
          runAsUser: 1000
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
          name: certs
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: esdata01
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeName: k8-worker-cpu-3.cines.fr
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: certs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: certs
      - name: esdata01
        persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: esdata01
```

I tried to curl localhost from the es01 container ( `curl -u elastic:generated_password localhost:9200` ) but got `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

I can access to Kibana through a browser and connect with the elastic/generated_password without any problem. I even managed to ingest some data in Elastic (that I could view through Kibana Dev Tools) but I feel like I should fix this error anyway.

Does anyone has a lead on how to debug this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had received the `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` error as well. Looking at the logs of my elasticsearch container, I saw:

```
elasticsearch  | {"@timestamp":"2023-10-24T12:12:56.851Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.27.0.2:9200, remoteAddress=/172.27.0.1:53556}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[675c0be8b915][transport_worker][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"aFQuvcOeTimpQSwtFIgzFg","elasticsearch.node.id":"b2ieytx7RY2ZmGuNTe8B3w","elasticsearch.node.name":"675c0be8b915","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
```

which indicated the server was expecting a secure request at port 9200.

I would suggest making a secure request: `curl -u elastic:generated_password https://localhost:9200`